# run swing application on browser

Tags: java, swing, applet, jnlp

I have one swing application that i want to run on browser.

What is the best way to achieve it ?
Is jnpl is one this solution ?

I tried jnpl but when i tries to run with -- http://localhost:8080/Test.jnlp -- One error window opens with error unable to launch application

If applet is the solution then , if possible please ,give me one sample applet application.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you get any errors in the java console that sheds some light on your issue?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, JNLP won't allow you to run your application a browser (as say the unofficial JNLP FAQ, [JNLP!=Applet](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#applets)). It will instead allow you to easily distribute current (and nexts) version of your application to your clients, by simplifying the install process.

The simple way to do it is to transform your application into a real applet (complet with all its usage restrictions), then make this applet detachable, using new Java6 feature. I unfortunatly only found info on that very excellent feature in [a blog post](http://stufffromjim.blogspot.com/2008/05/dragging-java-applets-out-of-browser.html).